# Generate a String Array with a different amount of Chars in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, combinations

I would need something like this:

```
[[i]++[j]| i <- ['a'..'d'], j <- ['a'..'d']] where I get the output:
["aa","ab","ac","ad","ba","bb","bc","bd","ca","cb","cc","cd","da","db","dc","dd"]
```

What I need is a more dynamical way to generate this output array. So if a get an Integer value 3 i should looks like:

```
[[i]++[j]++[k]| i <- ['a'..'d'], j <- ['a'..'d'], k <- ['a'..'d']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
replicateM n ['a'..'d']
```

`n` is the number of times to repeat.

Comment: but so I don't get the permutations I need. So I only get the output '["abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"]' if I take n = 5 or do I make something wrong?

Comment: You're writing `replicate`, not `replicateM`.

Comment: Okay, my fault :) Now I wrote replicateM but there the hugs compiler says: ERROR - Undefined variable "replicateM"

Comment: You need to import `Control.Monad`.

Comment: Thank you very much...that works great for me. Just found it a few seconds ago :)

Comment: Wow... My mind, she is blown. Still trying to figure out how this works... I'm impressed.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I wrote an explanation as a new answer, if you wanna take a look.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Louis Wasserman's answer a bit:

`replicateM i m` is equivalent to:

```
do a1 <- m
   a2 <- m
   a3 <- m
   ...
   ai <- m
   return [a1, a2, a3, ..., ai]
```

For example, `replicateM 3 getLine` is an `IO [String]` action that will get three lines and give you a list of strings:

```
do line1 <- getLine
   line2 <- getLine
   line3 <- getLine
   return [line1, line2, line3]
```

Now, remember that list comprehensions are just fancy syntax the `[] Monad`:

```
[[i, j] | i <- ['a'..'d'], j <- ['a'..'d']]

=

do i <- ['a'..'d']
   j <- ['a'..'d']
   return [i, j]
```

And that's exactly what `replicateM 2 ['a'..'d']` looks like.

Comment: ...and `replicate` (without the `M`) just takes an item and puts N of it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
seq i xs | i > 0 = [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- seq (i-1) xs]
         | otherwise = [[]]
```